# Spock @IgnoreIf based on properties file

Tags: java, groovy, spock

I want to ignore a test by taking values from properties file and then feeding them into the `IgnoreIf` predicate. Is this possible? If not, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Spock Manual, chapter "Extensions"](http://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/extensions.html), describes how to use bound variables like `sys`, `env`, `os`, `jvm`. But basically you can put any Groovy closure there.

If you specify environment variables or system properties on the command line when running your tests, you can just use `env` or `sys` in order to access them. But if you absolutely want to read the properties from a file, just use a helper class like this:

**File *spock.properties*:**

Probably you want to put the file somewhere under *src/test/resources* if you build with Maven.

```
spock.skip.slow=true
```

**Helper class reading the properties file:**

```
class SpockSettings {
    public static final boolean SKIP_SLOW_TESTS = ignoreLongRunning();

    public static boolean ignoreLongRunning() {
        def properties = new Properties()
        def inputStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("spock.properties")
        properties.load(inputStream)
        inputStream.close()
        //properties.list(System.out)
        Boolean.valueOf(properties["spock.skip.slow"])
    }
}
```

**Test using the helper class:**

```
import spock.lang.IgnoreIf
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.util.environment.OperatingSystem

class IgnoreIfTest extends Specification {
    @IgnoreIf({ SpockSettings.SKIP_SLOW_TESTS })
    def "slow test"() {
        expect:
        true
    }

    def "quick test"() {
        expect:
        true
    }

    @IgnoreIf({ os.family != OperatingSystem.Family.WINDOWS })
    def "Windows test"() {
        expect:
        true
    }

    @IgnoreIf({ !jvm.isJava8Compatible() })
    def "needs Java 8"() {
        expect:
        true
    }

    @IgnoreIf({ env["USERNAME"] != "kriegaex" })
    def "user-specific"() {
        expect:
        true
    }
}
```